# discord.py how to make a command have a cooldown?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

want to have this command on cooldown for 30 seconds

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,30,commands.BucketType.user) 
    if message.content.startswith('!sg hunt')
        await message.channel.send('You hunted a...')

@work.error
async def work_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f'This command is on cooldown, you can use it in {round(error.retry_after, 2)} seconds')
```

tried this buckettype thing

Comment: Should work, assuming you have a function definition in there that you forgot to copy paste. This should only allow the same user to use it once per 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

*Weidong Zhu Robot*!
You probably forgot to make function definition. Also `@client.command()` returns context, not message, so don't forget about this too.

There's your quick fix

````py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,30,commands.BucketType.user)
async def hunt_cmd(ctx):
    message = ctx.message
    if message.content.startswith('!sg hunt')
        await message.channel.send('You hunted a...')```
````

Comment: Why first words like "hey" disappear when i edit it?